# construct large square using smaller squares

Tags: math, dynamic-programming

I have a large square of edge `N`. I want to calculate the number of small squares required to construct this large square using smaller squares with edge values from `1` to `N-1`. I have unlimited number of such small squares.The only restriction is that I have to use the `minimum` number of smaller squares.For example,if N=3, I can construct this square using 5 squares of size `1` and 1 square of size `2`. How can I solve this problem for any given value of `N`?

Answer (score 0):

For even `N`, you can use 4 squares of side `N/2`, which is the minimum possible. For odd `N`, it's a bit more complicated. One possible solution for odd `N` is one square of `(N+1)/2`, 3 of `(N-1)/2`, and `N-1` of size 1, but I'm not entirely sure that's minimal... For example, if `N=9`, this would give 12 squares, where a better solution of 9 3x3 squares exists. It might be the best solution for prime `N`, though.