# How can i find the number of lowest possible square that can fit in the given square

Tags: c, algorithm, math

let's suppose i have a square of 7x7.i can fill the square with other squares(i.e the squares of dimension 1x1,2x2.....6x6).How can  i can fill the square with least possible smaller squares.please help me.

Comment: This isn't clear.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: See whathaveyoutried.com and the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: like if i have to fill square of 3X3 then i can fill the square with 9 1x1 square or with 1 2X2 and 5 1x1. since second option requires less number of squares.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MrsPerkinssQuilt.html

Comment: The same teacher? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688161/construct-large-square-using-smaller-sqaures

Comment: Well if the original square is `n x n` (where `n` is always an integer correct?) and `n` is divisible by 2 (AKA n is even), you can always fit exactly four `(n/2) x (n/2)` squares in it. And there isn't a way to fit 3 squares or 2 squares together to make another square so that solves it for half of all possible cases.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a square with dimensions `s x s`. Cutting a smaller square of dimensions `m x m` out will result in a square of `m x m`, a square of `n x n`, and two rectangles of dimensions `m x n`, where `m + n = s`.

When `s` is even, the square can be divided such that `m = n`, in which case the rectangles will also be squares, resulting in an answer of 4.

However, when `s` is odd, values of `m` and `n` must be chosen such that the resulting rectangle can be filled with the least number of squares possible. There doesn't seem to be an immediately obvious way to figure out the best configuration, so I would suggest coming up with an algorithm to figure out the least number of squares that can be used to fill a rectangle of size `m x n` (this is a slightly simpler problem and *I believe* it can be solved with a recursive algorithm). The total number of squares needed will then be equal to `2 x ([number of squares in m x n rectangle] + 1)`. You can use a loop to check all the sizes of m between `1` and `s/2`.

Hope that gets you started.

Comment: Not sure that solving for `m x n` is simpler, since `n x n` can be considered a special case of it.

Comment: "The total number of squares needed will then be equal to 2 x ([number of squares in m x n rectangle] + 1)."  This is not true! Consider n=4, m=3. Your suggestion to place a 3x3 opposite from the 4x4 would require 10 smaller squares, which is not optimal. Placing a 2x2 in the opposite corner cuts the number reqired to 9. I think it would be better to start by placing mxm squares in the adjacent corners of the nxn.

Comment: Hm, you're right. This problem is more complicated than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a square with dimensions s x s.
Factorialise `s` into primes. Then solve the problem for each prime `sp`. The answer will be the same for `sp x sp` as for `s x s`. It is probable that the smallest prime will give the lowest result. I have have no proof of this, but I have checked by hand up to 17 x 17. 
This is a generalisation of Otaias notion of an even `s` resulting in an answer of 4.

Placiing algorithm:

You need to loop from n = (s+1)/2, rounded down,  to n = s-1.

Put the n x n square in a corner.

Let m = s - n. 
Place m x m squares in the adjacent corners and keep placing them until they (almost) reach the end of the n x n square.

The remaining space will be m x m (if you are lucky), or up to 2m-1 x 2m-1 with a corner piece missing.

Fill the remaining space with a similar algorithm. Start with placing a n2 x n2 square in the corner opposite to the missing corner piece.

Working by hand I have obtained the following results:

```
s  minimum number of squares:
2   4
3   6
5   8
7   9
11  10
13  11
17  12
```

Comment: Your results don't seem right (you can't cover a 3x3 square with 5 squares). And even if you fix this, I don't see why you think that your algorithm is optimal.

Comment: And I understand it correctly, it isn't even fully specified: After repeating this process twice, you'll end up with a square that has two missing corners, and it isn't clear how to continue from there...

Comment: @interjay Sorry, a typo, should be 6 for the 3x3. And you are right, my answer isn't complete. It's as far as I got in the short time I've had to ponder it. I was hoping that others would find it promising and help improvew it further. If you want to solve this kind of problem in a reasonable time then every bit of informaton that can reduce the amount of brute-forcing necessary is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First check if n is even. If n is even, then the answer is four since there isn't a way to fit 3 squares or 2 squares together to make another square so that solves it for half of all possible cases

### BEFORE YOU PROCEED: This approach is incomplete and this may be the WRONG approach

I just intend to throw out an out-of-the-box idea just because I feel like this may help and, hopefully, advance the problem. I feel like it may have some correlation with [Goldbach's weak conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture). The algorithm may be too long to compute for larger values, and I'm not sure how much optimization is happening.

Now my idea would be to try to enumerate all triples `(n1,n2,n3)` where `n1 + n2 + n3 = n`  AND `n1, n2, n3` are all prime (which are  >= 2) AND `n >= 7` AND `n1 <= n2 <= n3`

Now let me literally depict my algorithm:

[image: My algorithm]

Now my idea is find all possible triples `(n1,n2,n3)` so it fits the definition stated above. Next set `n_s = n1 + n2`. IF `n_s > n3` follow the depiction above else flip `n_s` and `n3`

Now the problem is the white rectangles left over (that should be congruent to each other).

Let `n4 x n3` denote the rectangles where:

```
n4 = n - 2 * n3 \\if following the depicted example
```

Enumerate all possible triples `(n41, n42, n43)` (treating n as n = n4, so n3 >= 7) and `(n31, n32, n33)` (treating n as n = n3, so n3 >= 7). Next find the value where `n_s3 == n_s4` and both are the greatest they could be.
 For example:

Let's suppose `x3 = 17` and `x4 = 13`

```
  Enumeration of x3 = 17:
  2 + 2 + 13
  3 + 3 + 11
  5 + 5 + 7
  
  Enumeration of x_s3:
  4 = 2 + 2
  6 = 3 + 3
  10 = 5 + 5
  12 = 5 + 7
  14 = 3 + 11
  15 = 2 + 13
  
  Enumeration of x4 = 13:
  2 + 2 + 7
  3 + 5 + 5
  
  Enumeration of x_s4:
  4 = 2 + 2
  8 = 3 + 5
  9 = 2 + 7
  10 = 5 + 5
```

Since `10` is the largest value shared between 13 and 17, you fit a 10 by 10 square in the (both rectangles) and now you have a none parallelogram which get further and further more difficult to fill, but may be (I feel) towards the right direction.

All feed back appreciated.